# Compile only one class in a Scala program that contains more than one classes?

Tags: scala

I know a Scala file, as in Java, should better define only one class. But now I have someone else's code. The code defines two classes. I 'd like to compile one of them because the other one does not compile. Of course I could have commented out the other one, but I have a large number of such files and I am looking for an automated solution for doing so. Any idea?

Comment: The automated solution would do what? Read some external list of classes that should or shouldn't be compiled? If you have such a list somewhere anyway, why not save the same information in form of comments, excluding the broken classes?

Comment: Use ```sbt-assembly``` to have an executable file

Comment: By the way, there's no such rule in Scala. It is very common to define more than one class in a single file. It's even a requirement when defining sealed class hierarchies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scala compiler works on whole files. The only way I can imagine doing this is to write a script which comments out all classes you don't want, runs `scalac` and then removes the comment markers again (well, you could also use Scala compiler as a library to get equivalent results without doing this literally). Needless to say, I don't think it's actually a good idea, but it's possible.